# Can we use ExtJS4 without using MVC feature supported by EXTJS4?

Tags: extjs

We have a pretty complex application to be built. Planning to use EXTJS4. We have a team who is well versed with coding EXTJS3 style. We are researching on MVC feature of EXTJS4 and whether to go that way or not. Want to add that we will have really complex layouts and pages.

Can we use EXTJS4 without using MVC feature?

Comment: yes you can use it without MVC

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can... however if the only reason you are avoiding MVC is that someone on your team is "well versed in Ext JS 3 style" then you are in for a world of hurt.

Ext JS 4 is **very** different from Ext JS 3, in about a hundred thousand ways. The latest version is Ext JS 6.0.1 -- and follows all of the paradigms introduced in Ext JS 4.

TL;DR -- if you are serious about using Ext JS for large projects, (1) use the paradigms for the framework and (2) use the latest version!